# Indesign, Pantone+ are LAB colors?

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, pantone

I wonder if it is normal that Pantone+ are shown as LAB colors? [image: Image LAB color]
*(picture language is Dutch by the way)*

I never really pay attention until now..

I have also a preflight that complains for the LAB color and it says I need to check an option in 'ink management' > 'Standard Lab Values used for spot colors', anyone that knows what this option does exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's normal.

At version CS6 of the Adobe application the Pantone+ libraries were included. Pantone+ Libraries *only* have L*A*B definitions. Prior to CS6 and Pantone+ the Pantone Libraries had both CMYK and L*A*B definitions.

You can still use old Pantone libraries in newer versions of Adobe software if you'd prefer.

You can review the Adobe documents detailing this along with workarounds to use older libraries here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/kb/pantone-plus.html

Answer (score 1):

It is normal. CC has been using LAB to define PANTONE swatches for the last few versions.